# How can I switch the openAll() or closeAll() (button) from Angular Material expansion panel?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular11

I want to switch between 2 buttons: OpenAll and CloseAll.

Can I read a boolean of mat-accordion if it's all opened or closed?

```
<div class="row">
    <mat-icon *ngIf="accordion.open()" (click)="accordion.openAll()">open_in_full</mat-icon>
    <mat-icon *ngIf="!accordion" (click)="accordion.closeAll()">close_fullscreen</mat-icon>
</div>
<div class="message-box row" *ngIf="notes.length; else noResult">
    <mat-accordion multi>
        <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let note of notes" [expanded]="0">
            <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                <mat-panel-title class="col-6">
                    {{note.title}}
                </mat-panel-title>
                <mat-panel-description class="col-6">
                    {{note.created | date:'dd.MM.yyyy'}}
                </mat-panel-description>
            </mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <p>{{note.note}}</p>
        </mat-expansion-panel>
    </mat-accordion>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access `isExpanded` property.

See:
https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/api

Comment: I already tried, but I guess this works only for one expansion panel and there's not such an option to check if all panel are open or closed.